# Python Selenium how to find input button

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

On the website, the input tag is this:

```
<input value="Submit" type="submit">
```

How can I make selenium select this input button?

I tried this:

```
browser.find_element_by_css_selector("input[value='submit']")
```

But it wasn't able to find the input button.

Comment: use beautifulSoup ; for a in soup.find_all('input',{'value','Submit'}): ; print(a.get('type'))

Comment: For my project I have to use selenium

Comment: Should capitalize `Submit`, rather than `submit`?

Answer (score 1):

I would use this xpath to find the above ***input***:

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath(".//input[@value='Submit' and @type='submit']")
```

If there are multiple inputs with the same ***attributes***, you may need to find by index as well.

***UPDATE:***

Since you are having trouble finding the element, and there are no *iframes* on the page, I would suggest using `WebDriverWait` in case there are any ***AJAX/JavaScript/Dynamic load events*** that are creating the input **after** the pageload is complete.

Import these into your script:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

Then try this:

```
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 10)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, ".//input[@value='Submit' and @type='submit']"))).click()
```

---

As mentioned in your comment, you had to switch to a new tab. The way to do this in Selenium is:

```
#this will switch to the newest tab
browser.switch_to_window(browser.window_handles[-1])
```

Comment: `selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"
.//input[@value='Submit' and @type='submit']"}` Not working

Comment: Do you see an `iframe` or `frame` anywhere in the HTML?

Comment: No iframes on the page

Comment: `File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py", line 80, i
n until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:` No exception message. Still not working

Comment: Is the site public? Can you share the URL?

Comment: Also what versions of Chrome/chromedriver/Selenium are you on? If you are using Chrome that is.

Comment: I am unable to share the URL because it is a private login page, however, my selenium version is 3.12.0 and I am using chrome with the chromedriver.

Comment: I found out the issue. My browser was finding the elements in one tab and not the tab that was just click on.

Comment: Glad you found the issue, next time it would help if you added more `code` to your question so we can see the entire problem. Nice Job!

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that input tag is in the an iframe?

if it in an iframe you should use

`browser.switch_to.frame('iframe's id')` to enter the iframe, if you enter this frame, you can use xpath or css selector to find the tag you want.

Answer (score 0):

There's a clear mispelling, the 'Submit' value has a capitalised S in your sourcecode, but you have provided lowercase in your selector. Try this instead!

```
browser.find_element_by_css_selector("input[value='Submit']")
```